# Can't enter to bios in a Fujitsu Celsius H series

Tags: boot, bios

I'm trying to install Linux Mint on a Fujitsu Celsius H series using a USB stick. I would like to modify the boot options in the bios to can use USB to install the OS.

The problem is that I can't enter to bios because it asks for a password. I don't set any password before. When I enter a random password I get this message: `User not verified! Please retry authentication.`

I tried this method in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/913650/remove-fujitsu-lifebook-bios-password-on-startup#913788) but I didn't get any master password.

Please if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: enter a wrong password a few times until it outputs a code, post the code here in the comments.

Comment: @Moab it doesn't output any code, it shows a window with `User authentication failed ...`

Comment: Isn't that a little odd, I can't find any info...  You might want to open it up and remove the internal battery, put a new one in. Remove all power sources, and let the item site for about 20 mins. Press and hold the power button for about 20 seconds before you replace the internal (BIOS) battery, put the computer back together. The information found here and at the Fujitsu site is really helpful in letting me know never to purchace any Fujisu laptop or PC product for use, thanks for the post.