# Bypass BIOS on Fujitsu s710-Solved

Tags: bios

I'm facing problem on my old Fujitsu s710 laptop with Phoenix BIOS.
I tried this: [Remove Fujitsu Lifebook Bios Password on Startup](https://superuser.com/questions/913650/remove-fujitsu-lifebook-bios-password-on-startup).
After entering this 3 passwords: "3hqgo3", "jqw534", "0qww294e", I got the Hash key and entered it in python script, and received the master password.
But when I entered the password, It didn't work for me.
Is there some way to solve this problem?
I would be glad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I've just solved that with this site: https://1024kb.co.nz/bios/#keygen
But thanks anyways:)